# function to open a few new windows of random sizes and locations upon closing the browser

Tags: javascript, window.open

`function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;}
    window.onbeforeunload = exit
    function exit(){
        for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
            var a = getRandomInt(101, 1500);
            var b = getRandomInt(101, 1500);
            var c = getRandomInt(1, 1500);
            var d = getRandomInt(1, 1500);
            window.open('Site.html', 'newwindow', 'width = a, height = b, top = c, left = d');}
    return`null'

Can you pass a variable to window.open?

Comment: Are you aiming to adware spam someone when they close their browser?! lol Why spawn a bunch of Windows?

Comment: haha essentially.  Its a small game/prank just for my family members.

Comment: You know the saying "A new spammer has been born" typically around xmas time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to combine the toString(intVar) and "+" (concatenation) operator within your window.open specs param. (the 3rd bit within the parentheses)

Seems a nefarious motive to do this though. That worked 15 years ago. People know keyboard shortcuts to close things now. Plus, don't do that.

Comment: This is unless JS has smart string interpolation. If it does, look that up and use it. I work with Ruby really.

Comment: Somewhat nefarious.  More just a harmless prank on my parents.  So where exactly do you concatenate?  Before and after the toString? Like this: 'width = + a.toString() +, height = + b.toString() +.....?